# Adding padding -100px when scroll to the id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a navigation menu with with anchors to ids and I want to add some padding because part of the content isn't visible due to the navigation bar.

I was searching for some solutions and found this but it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

The website is http://testerks.futurehost.pl/intensedms. `#pm` is the div id

```html
scrollTop': $target.offset().top - ($('#pm').height() + 50
```

Answer (score 1):

This CSS tells the browser that, when it scrolls to #pm, to leave a 82px gap.

```
#pm {
   scroll-margin: 82px;
}
```

Further documentation and browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding

Answer (score 0):

You can substract height of nav, from div#pm's top offset which is 82px in your case.

```
$(window).scrollTop( $target.offset().top - 82)
```