# Scrolling to anchor on page results in element overlap

Tags: html, css, scroll, hyperlink, href

I have named a div id for example: `div id="page1"` and at the same page I have a link like: `a href="#page1"`.

However, my navigation menu is always on top, so it hides under the menu on scroll. How can I fix it so that it will scroll exactly on the div?

I can't figure out how it can scroll exactly to the div.

Comment: The best way will be just adding padding top and not margins

Comment: But for example if i link to #div2 the navigation menu overlaps it so you have to scroll a little bit up when clicking the link #div2

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cori-mm8xiq?file=/index.html You can look for that example. Here with bootstrap i put link to navbar where content in padding and to link where content with margin top

Comment: Thanks anyway, what worked for me is using CSS:
html { scroll-padding-top: 140px; }

Comment: A question with a better [mcve]: [add padding at the top after the standard scroll to the ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77198616/2943403) Related pages: [scroll-padding-top not working when anchor referenced from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71428030/2943403) and [Is it possible to get scroll-margin-top to work in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63637410/2943403) and [Adding padding -100px when scroll to the id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56864663/2943403) and [Sticky header input scrolls on input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65929206/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is using CSS:

```
html { scroll-padding-top: 140px; }
```