# add padding at the top after the standard scroll to the ID

Tags: html, css

I have 4 blocks, and links so that you can go to the desired block

How can I make it so that when I click on any link, and after I am redirected to the desired ID, this block will be padding at the top, say 40px?

Initially, these padding at the top are not needed, only after scrolling to the ID

```css
.menu {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.block {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: purple;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#block1">Go to Block 1</a>
  <a href="#block2">Go to Block 2</a>
  <a href="#block3">Go to Block 3</a>
  <a href="#block4">Go to Block 4</a>
</div>

<div id="block1" class="block">Block 1</div>
<div id="block2" class="block">Block 2</div>
<div id="block3" class="block">Block 3</div>
<div id="block4" class="block">Block 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scroll-margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top).

```css
.menu {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.block {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: purple;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  scroll-margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#block1">Go to Block 1</a>
  <a href="#block2">Go to Block 2</a>
  <a href="#block3">Go to Block 3</a>
  <a href="#block4">Go to Block 4</a>
</div>

<div id="block1" class="block">Block 1</div>
<div id="block2" class="block">Block 2</div>
<div id="block3" class="block">Block 3</div>
<div id="block4" class="block">Block 4</div>
```

Beside `scroll-margin-top` there is also a [scroll-padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top) property. You can read more about them in [this article](https://getpublii.com/blog/one-line-css-solution-to-prevent-anchor-links-from-scrolling-behind-a-sticky-header.html).